# Radius of a cube

Tags: python, math, maya

This may be a silly question, but I basically need to find the radius of a cube in MAya.

Or another explanation would be I need to find the absolute center point, to the axis of choice example Y, so it would find out the radius of the Y direction if specified, or the distance from the center point to the furthest X direction, this would be the "radius".

Would love the help!

Comment: Are you looking for the radius of the largest sphere that can fit inside of the cube, or the smallest sphere that the cube can fit inside of?

Comment: Init's sense yes, the largest sphere that would fit inside the boundires of a cube

Comment: The radius of that sphere would be half of the length of any edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: circle inscribed in square with radius shown to be half of length of side of square]

By analogy in 2 dimensions - or think of this as the center slice of the sphere in the cube.